# How to resolve inconsistent package warnings in conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, package, virtualenv, conda

Newer versions of Conda provide the user with more detailed information about inconsistent packages casuing conflict with the environment. One such package in my conda env is the `_nb_ext_conf` which according to anaconda cloud, is the latest  0.4.0 installed in my system and even then I'm receiving this warning when trying to install/update a module:

```
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing inconsistency:
 - defaults/osx-64::_nb_ext_conf==0.4.0=py36_1
```

This package cannot be removed, since its required by jupyterlab as well as notebook. I'm not sure if it's causing serious conflict since I haven't yet experienced anything getting broken, but I would still want to resolve this inconsistency. Is there a way I could fix it? I searched for similar questions in conda's issues section in github, but did not come across anything similar.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Run:

```
conda install anaconda
```

It may solve the problem.

If that doesn't work, run `conda install package_name` for the inconsistent packages to let conda try to restore consistency.

Else, run `conda update --all`

Comment: That actually worked. Strange the latest `_nb_ext_conf` still needed to be 'updated' to resolve the inconsistency.

Comment: `conda install anaconda` and `conda update --all` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the package causing inconsistency? It works for me.

Also, I recommend [everything](https://voidtools.com/) as a great search tool to find where your old package locates.

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - conda-forge/win-64::leidenalg==0.8.3=py37h3eba4e7_0
failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

After deleting the leidenalg package,

```
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
```

If you encountered the problem in Jupyter notebook, try change your python version in the

> kernel.json

file, as suggested in [this post](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4079#issuecomment-429475420).